# Edit text sort with background colors

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have 10 editText boxes in a table layout, each with a different background color.  Can I sort the editText boxes and keep the associated color with the value?  I'm sorting from largest value to smallest.  I want the color to remain with the value no matter what position it ends up after the sort.

Is there a structure I can use to associate the value with the background color and sort that way?  Any suggestions will help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Design a list adapter that returns (in the getview method) a textview filled with a value and whose background is set by the value of a hastable entry that maps each of your numeric value to a color.

more or less :

```
class ColorArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
    private Map<Integer, Integer> mapValueToColor = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    public CorArrayAdapter( List<Integer> listValues ) {
      super( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listValues );
    }

    getView(int row, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if( convertView == null ) {
            convertView = new TextView();
        }
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView;
        textView.setText( String.valueOf( listValues.get( row ) ) );
        textView.setBackground( mapValueToColor.get( listValues.get( row ) );
        return textView; 
    }
 }
```